# read(n) function returns less than n bytes and EOF not reached

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I am trying to parse a file and I encountered the following problem: While reading DWORDs from file I hit a point in which it reads only 1 byte instead of 4, and the EOF is **not** hit.

```
address_of_functions = []    
DWORD = "<I"
size_dword = struct.calcsize(DWORD)
f.seek(rva2fa(export_directory.AddressOfFunctions, section_header,nt_header.FileHeader.NumberOfSections), 0)
    for i in range(export_directory.NumberOfFunctions/2):
        buffer = f.read(size_dword)
        buffer1 = f.read(size_dword)
        print i, len(buffer)
        print i, len(buffer1)
        address_of_functions.append(struct.unpack(DWORD, buffer))
```

And here is a photo of the output where I encounter the problem:
[image]

Why that string of length 1 occurs? I know for a fact that I can read the entire list.

**EDIT**
The NumberOfFunctions is 1364 so it is not of that.
The file that I am trying to parse is `kernel32.dll`  so no unwanted EOF should be there.

Comment: You don't show the code where you open the file - did you open it "rb"?

Comment: is there an unwanted EOL at the end of the file? `\n`?

Comment: Your indentation seems to be erratic, and Python does not like erratic indentation.

Comment: does the value of `NumberOfFunctions` match the contents of the file (i.e. twice the number of functions present)?

Comment: Have you tried printing the data that was read, along with its length? That might easily shed some light on what is happening.

Comment: @barny no, I opened it with "r"

Comment: @TomZych that is the output from, printing the index and the length

Comment: @Tandura: Yes, I see that. But it may be revealing to look at the actual characters in `buffer` and `buffer1`. Better still, open with `rb`, which will result in `read` returning `bytes` objects, and look at the contents in hex.

Answer (score 0):

If a file is binary -- that is, it may include bytes with any value, not just printable characters -- you *must* open it in binary mode "rb".

This is especially true on Windows, because if you open the file in text mode, the underlying system library read function will report an EOF if it sees a byte whose value is 26 (hex 0x1A), which corresponds to Ctrl-Z.

Opening the file in binary mode avoids this and other inconveniences.